# JQuery conflict with C# InnetHtml

Tags: c#, jquery-mobile

When adding the JQuery JS  include the InnetHTML is not working:

My HTML code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="aaa.aspx.cs" Inherits="aaa" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" 
/> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <div id="ppdiv" runat="server">


            </div>


        </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" Text="Button" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class aaa : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ppdiv.InnerHtml = "aaa";
    }
}
```

when include JQUery the InnetHTML is not working. Where is the error and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you don’t have Any include of jQuery in this code. Second: InnerHtml server side and client side are working differently

Comment: You didn't add jQuery. The reference that you've added is a style sheet(.css). So this code should works fine. What is your problem?

Comment: sorry. that is the iclude that coz the InnetHTML not to work: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: Still I can't see any part of your code which prevent `InnetHTML` to show `aaa`!

Comment: Your written code has't any problem!

Comment: thanks for checking this. but when we remove the JQuery JS from the html file the innerHtml is working fine. when we add back the JQueru JS include the Inner is not working.

Comment: change place of your scripts from head to end of your page befor </body>

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is because you are using runat="server" in head within which you add the jquery. jquery and javascript for client side, and runat="server" posts the data to server. remove runat="server" from head and check.

Comment: Hi , still the same ( after remove the run at server ). is there any other way to force the innethtml updated ?

Comment: i tried the same code as yours and found innerHTML working with/without runat="server" and jquery

Comment: Hi Roy , thanks for testing that. we are struggling here to find out what coz that in our environment. that is critical for us. Do you think we should Install another version of VS ?

Comment: its not about the VS version.. i dont think think target framework affecting this either, to check can you tell me which framework version.

Comment: Roy , I found on stackoverflow example using  HtmlTextArea with InnerHtml  and that it works !!!! Thank for your advice to avoid  environment change.